# Do all email addresses need to be Google Apps accounts if I switch to Google Apps?

Tags: email, google-workspace

I'm looking at using Google Apps for my domain. I currently have several email addresses for the domain.

Would I need to create users for all the addresses? I would like to have one account that uses Google Apps and the rest would not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

In the "Full administrative and data control" section of the [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/details.html) it states:

> Email routing and email gateway support let you run Google Apps alongside an existing email solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can in fact keep your old mail server for all users, and use Google Apps Gmail for yourself at the same time, but it comes with some manual administration.

If you choose this dual setup (as I have done in a looong migration phase), then here's how:

Turn on Google Apps and Apps Gmail. The Apps Dashboard will complain a little because the MX record still points to your old mail server and not to Gmail. But it works!

You can send mails from Apps Gmail, and replies go to your old mail server -- where you should add forwarding rules to your new Gmail address. In the Users section of the Apps Dashobard, you can see that your Gmail has the address of `yourname@yourdomain.com.test-google-a.com`. In your old mailbox, set up forwarding to this address, and you'll receive your mail in Gmail, too.

Do that for each mailbox that needs to be migrated, leave others unchanged. Migrated users can use Gmail, others won't ever notice anything.

Only switch the MX record to Google Apps once everybody has started using Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the email functionality of Google Apps.  If all you want to use is the other applications (Docs, Calendar, etc) then just don't configure the email functionality.

If however you are asking if you can have email accounts on both Google Apps and your existing solution then no, not really.  What you can do is set up forwarding in one direction or the other, so your email for most users stays on your existing solution but for that one user it can be forwarded to a gmail account.  Or you can setup a Gmail account and get it to import existing emails from your existing solution via Pop3 or Imap.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly but it may assist with your configuration if you do switch over to google apps.

> I currently have several email
>   addresses for the domain. Would I need
>   to create users for all the addresses?

You don't necessarily need to setup accounts for every email address.
Google Apps also has the concepts of 'nicknames' and 'groups'.

[Nicknames](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327) can be used to receive email from address such as webmaster@mydomain to your personal email account i.e. wookiebreath@mydomain. In this instance you only have the one account (wookiebreath) but are receiving email from two addresses.

[Groups](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33329) can be used to allow multiple accounts to receive messages from the one address.
For example you can create a group at sales@mydomain and have those emails distributed to wookiebreath@mydomain and wookiebreathJunior@mydomain. In this instance you have two accounts (wookiebreath and wookiebreathJunior) and they will receive any email sent to sales@mydomain (as well as any email sent to their specific account or nicknames).

Oh there is also a 'catchall' option, which will receive all emails sent to your domain that don't have an account, or nickname, or group associated with them. Can result in a lot of spam but google is pretty good at filtering a lot of that.